# Sharing parameters between intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm a beginner on dialogflow so maybe what I'm trying to archieve has some concept problem. I have two Intens: "Show options" and "Validate options". The context "ShowOptions" is configured as output on the intent "Show options" and as an input on the intent "Validate options". On the fulfillment functions I'm just trying to add a parameter on the context and when the "Validate options" intent is invoked I'm trying to get that parameter. When the "Validate options" intent is invoked I get an error an nothing is returned. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the code of my fulfillment:

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function showOptions(agent)
  {
    var messageText = 'Some text...';   

    agent.add(messageText);
    agent.setContext({name: "ShowOptions", lifespan: 50, parameters: {options: messageText}});
  } 


  function validateOptions(agent)
  {
    var optionContext = agent.getContext('ShowOptions');
    agent.add(optionContext.parameters.options);    
  }
  
  
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Show options', showOptions);
  intentMap.set('Validate options', validateOptions);
  
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

The "Validate options" intent has a parameter called optionName. The Raw API response returns this when the intent "Validate options" is invoked with optionName = "text":

```
{
  "responseId": "3f2048bc-08fc-4fb6-b0c2-45f6cc8abf55-ee7586fb",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "option text",
    "parameters": {
      "optionName": "text"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/project_id/agent/sessions/d44625bf-d6ec-2c4b-e2a3-587c72d88fe0/contexts/showoptions",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          "optionName.original": "text",
          "optionName": "text",
          "options": "Some text..."
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/project_id/agent/intents/55d504fb-cabd-4558-8054-e05177d3b362",
      "displayName": "Validate options"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.53878456,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 120
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error that you are getting to the question?

Comment: I added some info and the Raw API response that I'm getting.

Comment: The “code 14: Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE." means that the webhook that your code is attempting to trigger is not available or not found, could you confirm that the 'Show options' and 'Validate options' webhooks names are the same as the one you created in the Dialogflow Dashboard? It is case sensitive and must be the same, also, you can test your webhooks by going to Fulfilment->Inline Editor before deploying it externally.

Comment: Ok, I solve the issue by calling the function in this way:                                                        var optionContext = agent.getContext('showoptions'); Why all the contexts are created in lower case, even if I named them with upper case characters ??

Comment: According to documentation [1], when using the API all context names are lowercase

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-manage#name

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Still, the documentation also says that names are not case sensitive. It´s kind of confusing...either way problem solved.

Comment: I would like to know if you could share with the community the steps followed from your end to solve the issue that you were presenting by posting an answer, this is an interesting issue with the documentation that you could also report by downvoting on the Rate and review small situated on the right and above section of the documentation site [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-manage#name